# Should the Repository pattern manipulate an object before passing it to the consumer/service layer?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns, repository

The current solution I am working with is structured with a single Core layer that is connecting to the database whenever it needs to retrieve data.

I suggested to a few colleagues that we create a DAL layer and move all of the database logic into it's own project and call it

```
Application.DataAccess
```

This layer will use Entity Framework and the repository pattern as an abstraction between Application.Core and Application.DataAccess (The Repository implementation will sit within Application.DataAccess).

I plan to to consume the repository in a service layer.

```
public class JobService
{
   private IJobRepository _jobRepository;

   public JobService(IJobRepository repository) 
   {
      _jobRepository = repository;
   }

   public IEnumerable<Job> GetJobs() 
   {
      List<Jobs_AllJobs> allJobs = _jobRepository.GetAllJobs();
      List<Job> result = new List<Job>();

      foreach(job in allJobs) 
      {
        result.Add(new Jobs() { Title = job.Title, OtherEntity = "Internal to the service"; });
      }          

      return result;
  }
}
```

**Job Repository:**

```
public class JobRepository : IRepository<Jobs_AllJobs>
{
     DBContext _jobContext;

     public List<Jobs_AllJobs> GetJobs() 
     {
         return _jobContext.Jobs_AllJobs.ToList();
     }
}
```

This is where it gets slightly heated between us.

I believe that the JobRepository should return a list of the database entity `Jobs_AllJobs` rather than manipulate the database entity and construct a new List of `Job` (This should be handled in the service layer).  My colleagues believe that the manipulation should be done at the Repository level and that the JobRepository should pass back a `List<Job>` or `IEnumerable<Job>` rather than the database entity.

From my understanding the Repository pattern is meant abstract away the internal database implementation (Entity Framework/nHibernate/File System) and solely perform a CRUD operation upon database (Create, Retrieve, Update or Delete) and that the JobService should perform the manipulation and construct a new object and pass that back down to the consumer.

Which way would be correct? And which way follows the repository pattern the best?

Comment: The repository's interface should be defined in domain terms so it should return `Job` instances. `Jobs_AllJobs` is an infrastructure representation which should not bleed into the rest of the application. Ask yourself what would happen if multiple services needed to deal with `Job`s? Your code would be littered with infrastructure-level transformations from `Job` to `Jobs_AllJobs` and vice-versa.

Comment: @plalx - thanks for your comment. So it's acceptable that the JobRepository does the manipulation?  I think we will also have to have a Application.Model (Which stores the Job class) as Application.DataAccess and Application.Core will both depend on this.

Comment: Not only it's acceptable, but it's desirable. The role of the repository is to abstract away persitence concerns. Look at the layered architecture with the Dependency inversion principle applied and this pretty much the architecture you are looking for.